# How to change text direction of every line of text using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, text

Who can help with text direction change on each new line.
 **Here is example:**

```
text left-to-right
text right-to-left
text left-to-right
text right-to-left... etc.
```

On each `word-wrap: break-word` i need text direction change. Please, help! It could be jquery or javascript code.

Example below, but it was made with css and paragraphs. I need change text direction without paragraphs, or which is into the one paragraph on word-wrap.

Unfortuanelly I have no ideas how to make this, really...

```css
.ltr {
  direction: ltr;
  }
.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
  }
```

```html
<p class="ltr">Some text ltr</p>
<p class="rtl">ltr txet emoS</p>
<p class="ltr">Some text ltr</p>
<p class="rtl">ltr txet emoS</p>
<p class="ltr">Some text ltr</p>
<p class="rtl">ltr txet emoS</p>
```

Comment: Can you post a better example which could clarify what exactly you want. And please show us what have you tried?

Comment: Added visual example on jsfiddle

Comment: You should select every row of text using regex and set it into `p` tag dynamicaly and then change direction of every p. If you want use this solution, i posted answer.

Comment: You won't be able to do this using css `word-wrap:break-word` - you could apply word-wrap via javascript (there's likely a plugin), which would give you control/feedback as to where the newlines are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select every line of text by regex and set it in `p` tag using [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). Now you can change direction of every line by changing CSS of relevant `p`.

```
$("div").html(function(i, text){
    return text.replace(/(.+\n?)/g, "<p>$1</p>");
});
```

```js
$("div").html(function(i, text){
  return text.replace(/(.+\n?)/g, "<p>$1</p>");
});
```

```css
div > p:nth-child(odd){
   direction: ltr;
}
div > p:nth-child(even){
   direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
text left-to-right
text right-to-left
text left-to-right
text right-to-left... etc.
</div>
```